# How can I add any empty row after each seven rows inside table dynamic layout?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

What I have is two arrays one is static string array and the other one is an array list .. what I want to do is to make a table dynamic layout and rows to it dynamically which works just fine .. and what I am trying to do is to add a single row after each seven rows with a different source of data but it keeps adding it after the 14 rows, which is so weird. Please any smart solution for this problem? Here is my android activity code:

```
public class ProductInfoDetails extends Activity{
    private static final String product = "product";
    private static final String quantity = "quantity";
    private static final String unit = "unit";
    private static final String price = "price";
    private static final String totalprice = "totalprice";
    private static final String totalpriceafterdiscount = "totalpriceafterDiscount";
    private static final String note = "note";

    ArrayList<String> prodlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    int count;
    int fixed;
    String text[]={product,quantity,unit,price,totalprice,totalpriceafterdiscount,note};

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.penddinginfodetails);

        try{

        prodlist = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("prodlist");

            count=prodlist.size();
            fixed=count/7;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("prodlist",prodlist+"");
        Log.e("count",count+"");//14
        Log.e("fixed",fixed+"");//2




        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
    int razan=0;
        for(int s=0; s<fixed;s++){
            if(razan<=count){
                for (int i = 0; i <text.length; i++) {

                    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
                    TableRow.LayoutParams tr = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row.setLayoutParams(tr);

                    TextView product = new TextView(this);
                    TextView product_j = new TextView(this);


                    product_j.setText(prodlist.get(razan));
                    product_j.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));
                    product_j.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


                    product.setText(text[i]);
                    product.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));
                    product.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                    row.addView(product_j);
                    row.addView(product);

                    ll.addView(row,i);
                    razan++;

                    //here is the code for adding an empty row after each seven inner rows !!!
                    if(i % 7==0){
                        TableRow row1= new TableRow(this);
                        TableRow.LayoutParams tr1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        row1.setLayoutParams(tr1);

                        TextView emptyrow = new TextView(this);
                        emptyrow.setText("sereen");
                        emptyrow.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));

                        row1.addView(emptyrow);

                        ll.addView(row1);
                    }
                }//inner for

            }

    }//outer fors

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are seven items in text[].

```
for (int i = 0; i <text.length; i++)
```

so i will have values 0 to 6

```
if(i % 7==0)
```

This will be true for i == 0. And never for 1== 7 as i==7 does not occur.

Comment: so shall i change it to 6? or what shall i change?

Comment: Please now that you know what is going on you can rethink the logic.

Comment: i have changed the condition to if(i >0 && i%6==0) .. but still it adds out side the rows .. can you help me out again? @greenapps

Comment: Just add an empty row after the body of the loop: for (int i = 0; i <text.length; i++) { .... }

Comment: if(i >0 && i%6==0) should work or better: if ( i==6 ). Because in this loop you add everytime 7 rows and you do not add rows at other places. I wonder what the meaning is of razan. It looks like the total amount of rows added.

Comment: how can i add an empty row after the loop? can i add an view inside it?   ll.addView(row1); like this?